# About the ASP.NET page life cycle, and how to add a throbber while waiting for postback results

Tags: asp.net, .net

I can't seem to get my head around the ASP.NET page life cycle and its practical implications. What I'm trying to do is load a throbber image after the user clicks a submit button, then have that throbber disappear after the page reloads with a datagrid. Would someone try to enlighten me please? TIA!

Comment: The most important thing about the ASP.Net page lifecycle is that it runs on the **server**.  To show a throbber on the client before you start running the server-side code, you need Javascript.

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RegisterOnSubmitStatement` to run some javascript function when the page is submited that shows an image.

```
var script = "document.getElementById('MyImage').style.display = 'block'";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(), "ShowImage", script);
```

To make an animated gif animate during postback with IE (known bug) do the following (using jQuery):

```
var src = $theImge.attr("src");
$theImge.attr("src", "test.png"); //can be anything
$theImge.attr("src", src);
$theImge.hide();
$theImge.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus and Aristos! I was able to implement Magnus' solution--only thing is that the .GIF image isn't animating when it appears.  :-S  I implemented the solution as follows:

Comment: `code`
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  var script = "document.getElementById('throbber').style.display = 'inline-block'";
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(GetType(), "ShowThrobber", script);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    // load data for dropdown list
    }
    else
    {
    // some function...
    }
  }
`code`Any ideas about the non-animating .GIF?